# Select2 not highlighting the preselected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Hi I seem to be having problems getting the highlighted selection into view on the dropdown in the latest select2.

Here is an example, if you go and

1. select option 12
2. click outside the dropdown to close it
3. reselect the dropdown to view the current selection

http://jsfiddle.net/46f9c7jy/49/

```
  function formatFA(icon) {

      return '<img src="http://placehold.it/200x150">'+'<p>'+icon.text+'</p>';

  };
  $('#gyr_ind').select2({
      templateResult: formatFA,
                escapeMarkup: function (m) {
                return m;
              }   
  });
```

here you notice the option you previously selected "Option 12" isn't scrolled into view, instead I get the view of half of option 9 and half of option 10.

The closest match of the issue I could find was this link that mentions the issue is fixed. Am I missing an option or something or is this a bug because I can't get it to work and make sure the default view on the dropdown is always the current selected option

https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2586